# Continues Pinging to background, save logs and show statistics

Tags: ping

I'm trying to make a script that save the `ping` logs to .txt or .log file.
To monitor if my connection is intermittent or not, I'm using this script:

```
$nohup ping 8.8.8.8 > timeout.txt &
```

Then when I check if its pinging:

```
$tailf timeout.txt
```

It's working! But when I stop the process by using:

```
$kill (process)
```

timeout.txt file is stop pinging but didn't show the statistic logs if I had any timeout or packet loss.

How to stop the `ping` and also showing the statistic?
Or do I have to add a script to my script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
kill -SIGQUIT `pgrep ping`
```

to show statistics and do not stop ping.

```
kill -SIGINT `pgrep ping`
```

to show statistics as usual (e.g., when you press ctrl-c in terminal) and stop ping.

Comment: For OS X it's `SIGINFO`. You can also press `Ctrl-T` if the process is in the foreground (or `Ctrl-\ ` for `SIGQUIT` OSes).